# ASP Webservice executable as service (SOAP)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, service, daemon

I am currently working with an webservice that gives a URL as following;

```
https://webservices/app.exe/wsdl/MyWeb
```

The responses for the type of information it is requiring is SLOW.
I don't have access to the actual application, however it would seem that is loading up the application everytime which is why it is slow.

I am wondering if I can run a seperate application that keeps a connection open to `app.exe` then I can pass the parameter, thus removing the need to load up the app each time and speed up the responses.

The webservice is is a SOAP endpoint.

Comment: _"it would seem that is loading up the application everytime"_ - that is a very bold assumption to make, hard to prove and hard to circumvent. Why don't you contact the company behind those webservices and ask your question to them? The point is, yes, HTTP can keep a connection open, but only if both parties support it.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster - Yes I have clearly spoken to the company, great advice. My assumption on that is the SQL it is running takes ~1s to fire yet the response takes ~20s to create, plus the application is in the URL, so i don't think it is 'very bold'. Thank you for your unhelpful response.

Comment: The fact that the URL contains `app.exe` does definitely not mean that an instance of that executable is fired up for each request. Have you tried using HTTP keepalive as I suggested? Anyway, you can make many assumptions, but without any proof **for us**, we can't say anything meaningful about that.